# How to get ["error"]["type"] from error.userInfo in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nserror, userinfo

I am wondering how do we do this in Swift?

I am trying to convert the code below to Swift

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // handle successful response
        } else if ([[error userInfo][@"error"][@"type"] isEqualToString: @"OAuthException"]) { // Since the request failed, we can 
            NSLog(@"The facebook session error");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Some other error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

Here is what I've done.

```
request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // handle successful response
        }
        else if error.userInfo["error"]["type"] == "OAuthException" { 
           //THIS LINE WONT COMPILE

        }
        else {
            println("Some other error");
        }
    }
```

But I get a compile error that says `could not find member 'subscript'` on this line

```
error.userInfo["error"]["type"] == "OAuthException"
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Could you please let us know what XCode version are you using?

Comment: You need to cast your `userinfo` like `error.(userInfo as [String] [String])[...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if (error.userInfo?["error"]?["type"] as? String) == "OAuthException" {
```

`userInfo` is an optional dictionary of type `[NSObject: AnyObject]?` so you'll need to unwrap it.  Dictionary lookups always return an optional (because the key might not exist) so you have to unwrap it before accessing the key of the nested dictionary.  Using a `?` instead of `!` is *optional chaining* and it will harmlessly result in `nil` if the `"error"` key doesn't exist (instead of crashing if you use a `!`).  Finally, you'll need to cast the result to `String` (from `AnyObject`) in order to be able to compare it to `"OAuthException"`.

Comment: This doesn't work, still same error message. thanks though

Comment: I just looked it up.  `userInfo` is of type `[NSObject: AnyObject]?` so you'll need to unwrap it as well.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: may I know where did you look it up at?

Comment: option-click is your friend.  I typed `let u = NSError().userInfo
` in a Playground and option-clicked on `userInfo` and the pop up tells the type.

Comment: I'm not sure when it changed, but NSError.userInfo is no longer an optional.

Answer (score 0):

How about breaking down the error and type as shown below?

```
           else if let errorOAuthException: AnyObject =  error.userInfo as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{

            if errorOAuthException["error"] != nil {
                if errorOAuthException["type"] as? String == "OAuthException" {

                //Do something for me
                }
            }


        }
```